# Will the list of groups which have been assigned the db_owner role appear when command 'sp_helprolemember db_owner' is executed?

Tags: sql-server

So when my DBA executed the command 'sp_helprolemember db_owner' I can see three users:
dbo
XXX_PROD
XXX_WEB

Also, when my DBA executed the command 'SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins' I could see the following AD group:
Domain_company\XXX_PRODDB

When I requested for the permissions assigned to this group, I could see that db_owner was assigned to it in the Database Role Membership section.

Wanted to understand the following:

1. Since db_owner is assigned to a group here, will the group name not appear when the command 'sp_helprolemember db_owner' under the 'MemberName' column?
2. If the answer to the above statement is No, does it mean that information was given to me from two separate databases?
3. If a user is granted access to db_owner, does that mean they have write access to the entire database?

Fairly new to this. Would appreciate any help you send my way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Login and User are two different things. Login is server level while user is database level. Since db_owner is database level privilege so a user will be given this permission which will be linked to the login.

In your case `Domain_company\XXX_PRODDB` is the login and this login must be having a associated used under the database. And this user must be among `dbo, XXX_PROD, XXX_WEB`

So output of `sp_helprolemember` and `SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins` are correct. Its just the former will show you database level user and the latter will show you server level login.